# Joomla trim a class

Tags: joomla, texttrimming

Hy everyone I got this code

```
<?php if($this->item->params->get('itemRelatedIntrotext')): ?>
            <div class="itemRelIntrotext"><?php $new_string = substr($item->introtext, 0, 220); echo $new_string; ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

is bringing introtext, but its bringing the text with all the html code

```
<p class="mmbodytext">Dentro del <strong>Plan Estratégico</strong> de la campaña y como una de las líneas de acción de la comunicación está el <strong>Marketing Online</strong>. Su función, educar una...</p>
```

When the text is called i need to remove class="mmbodytext" and  from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are searching for an easy way to remove all tags you could use `strip_tags()`.

```
<?php echo substr(strip_tags($item->introtext), 0, 220); ?>
```

Reference: [strip_tags](https://php.net/strip_tags)

Answer (score 0):

Just figure it out...

```
<?php if($this->item->params->get('itemRelatedIntrotext')): ?>
            <div class="itemRelIntrotext"><?php $new_string = substr($item->introtext, 0, 220); ?>
            <?php $string = $new_string;
                $wordlist = array("mmbodytext","<strong>");

                foreach ($wordlist as $word) {
                    $string =str_replace($word, '', $string);
                }
                echo $string;
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not a need for foreach loop, you could add the array directly: `$string =str_replace($wordlist, '', $string);`.